# Change Project Owner Using PSI 2010(Project Server Interface)

Tags: c#, project-server, psi

I want to change ProjectOwnerUID Using PSI(Project Server Interface).I wrote that with follow similar code

```
var projectDataSet = this.GetProjectDataSet(projectInfo.ProjectUID);
        var orginalProject = this.GetProject(projectInfo.ProjectUID, projectDataSet);
        var sessionUID = this.CheckOutProject(projectInfo.ProjectUID);
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(projectInfo.ProjectOwnerName))
        {
            var resourceManager = new Resource();
            var ownerResource = resourceManager.GetResource(projectInfo.ProjectOwnerName);
            if (ownerResource == null)
            {
                throw new Exception("this is not valid");
            }
            orginalProject.ProjectOwnerID = ownerResource.ResourceUID;
        }


this.UpdateProject(sessionUID, projectDataSet);
```

unfortunatly when cursor arrive to UpdateProject line it throws exception with code number

> ProjectServerError(s) LastError=ProjectInvalidOwner Instructions: Pass this into PSClientError constructor to access all error information
>
> Inner Error 1056(Invalid project owner).

I don't know what happen that Issued this exception
how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs when you do not have permissions to edit project information using the following code snippet u can tell to project server to run this piece of code do not check permissions!!

```
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
    public void MyVoid()
    {
       SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
                {    
                  //Write ur Codes here :)

                });
    }
```

[MSDN Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsecurity.runwithelevatedprivileges.aspx)